# GDAL : transfer metainformation

Tags: gdal, photogrammetry, gdalinfo, agisoft-photoscan

I'm using Agisoft Photoscan 1.4.2 to build DEM from UAV photos and in last versions thay produce DEM multipage tiff format and I want to convert it to tiff with metainformation preserved.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38785793/1179925), I use vips to convert multipage tiff to tiff, but it drops all metainformation:

```
sudo apt-get install libvips-tools
vips im_vips2tiff dem_1_ctb.tif:0 1.tif
```

Then I wrote python script using GDAL api:

```
from osgeo import gdal, gdalconst

src = gdal.Open('dem_1_ctb.tif', gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
dst = gdal.Open('1.tif', gdalconst.GA_Update)

prj=src.GetProjection()
print('prj:', prj) #

gtr = src.GetGeoTransform()
print('gtr:', gtr) #

dst.SetProjection(prj)
dst.SetGeoTransform(gtr)
```

Original metainformation obtained by gdalinfo:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: dem_1_ctb.tif
Size is 1773, 1603
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (31.826655569140200,59.242815662671902)
Pixel Size = (0.000002169874100,-0.000001111660512)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  31.8266556,  59.2428157) ( 31d49'35.96"E, 59d14'34.14"N)
Lower Left  (  31.8266556,  59.2410337) ( 31d49'35.96"E, 59d14'27.72"N)
Upper Right (  31.8305028,  59.2428157) ( 31d49'49.81"E, 59d14'34.14"N)
Lower Right (  31.8305028,  59.2410337) ( 31d49'49.81"E, 59d14'27.72"N)
Center      (  31.8285792,  59.2419247) ( 31d49'42.88"E, 59d14'30.93"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
  Overviews: 887x802, 444x401, 222x201
  Unit Type: metre
```

Transfered metainformation:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 1.tif
Size is 1773, 1603
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (31.826655569140200,59.242815662671902)
Pixel Size = (0.000002169874100,-0.000001111660512)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=3 (pixels/cm)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=10
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=10
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  31.8266556,  59.2428157) ( 31d49'35.96"E, 59d14'34.14"N)
Lower Left  (  31.8266556,  59.2410337) ( 31d49'35.96"E, 59d14'27.72"N)
Upper Right (  31.8305028,  59.2428157) ( 31d49'49.81"E, 59d14'34.14"N)
Lower Right (  31.8305028,  59.2410337) ( 31d49'49.81"E, 59d14'27.72"N)
Center      (  31.8285792,  59.2419247) ( 31d49'42.88"E, 59d14'30.93"N)
Band 1 Block=1773x16 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

As I can see some of the metainformation is different, is it harmful? can it be transferred completely?

Comment: The answer to this question may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115552/is-there-image-editing-software-that-will-not-alter-a-geotiffs-embedded-georefe