# Updating Georeferenced Imagery?

Tags: raster, editing, georeferencing

I created a photomerged aerial image in Photoshop and i need to update a small section but, don't want to georeference the entire thing all over again.

How can i replace the imagery?

I am not changing the overall size or anything other than swapping out an bad area.

Comment: What happened when you tried simply editing/updating a copy of your georeferenced image?

Comment: Would the workflow of export-import georeferencing suit for your use case https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115552/is-there-image-editing-software-that-will-not-alter-a-geotiffs-embedded-georefe/115560#115560?

Comment: It is difficult to know but could you show us your screenshot ?